# How to implement Auth::check() in laravel and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

how to check user login? if the user is not logged in, the user cannot submit comments, and redirect to the login page for login first.

I've try, but didn't work

Comment: is it in vuejs .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes check in vuejs. but for the controller, i used laravel

Comment: and which auth you are using for vuejs login.?

Comment: @KamleshPaul no, for login i'm using laravel, but for form comment i'm using component vue

Comment: then when user enter comment let them enter but when comment hits to server you can check. if user is not login you can send response false and inside `vuejs` you can do if response is false then `window.location.href="login"`

Comment: @KamleshPaul oke, but how im implement in laravel?

Comment: comment hits to server means laravel end . how your are posting comment.?

Answer (score 3):

Protect your route with the authentication middleware:

```
Route::get('comments', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

or as a group:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::post('comments', 'CommentController@store');
    });
```

Then laravel will automatically redirect unauthenticated users to your 'login' named route. *(or specify a custom route in the redirectTo() method of app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php)*

From your ajax call in vue, you can listen for a 403 response code and then redirect the user to the login url. But if you put your main app's route in the auth middleware, you will never have to worry about this part, since laravel will redirect users automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how you built your application if it is an spa, you should use something like laravel airlock or passport instead of the default login logic.

If this is a multipage application, you should include a simple auth middleware.

With that you could simply tell in your blade file which elements shall be included or not like this:

```
@auth
  <h1>Logged in</h1>
@endauth
```

You could have a simple route which checks wether you are logged in or not, depending on the result you can do some magic.

Your route:

```
use Auth;

Route::get('is-auth', function () {
    $auth = Auth::user();
    return $auth;
});
```

Now you save the user to the global window object.

In generel you could do something like this, but I do not recommened the ideas below.

You could then sent a request to the server, which I do not recommend and get the result if you are logged in or not.

```
axios.get('is-auth')
   .then(response => {
     if(response.data) {
        console.log("not logged in");
     }
     console.log("logged in");
   });
   .catch(error => console.log("error");
```